# How to use Window.OnClose

Tags: asp.net

Work on C# asp.net vs05.i want when the user closes the browser window with the X in
the top right corner.. i want to open a goodbye message, if the user click ok then close if click cancel then not close.

Comment: Yes, people are much more likely to help you out if you accept correct answers.  As silly as it sounds, most of us have at least some level of satisfaction in knowing that we were the one to provide the correct answer.  If you've never done it, maybe you don't realize it, but you accept answers by clicking on the check mark next to the answer that worked,  So, I would humbly suggest that you do that for @Himadri's answer, since he was kind enough to answer and his answer IS correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<html>
<body onUnLoad='alert("Goodbye!")'>
<h1>Hello?</h1>
</body>
</html>
```